# I have to realize a method findWord, that finds index of word in a text and then adds it into int array, Someone can help me?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public int[] findWord(String text, String word) throws NullPointerException {

        // my code must be here
        return ;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything? Just asking us to write your code is not the way it works on that site. Try to write your code, and if you have errors or something, ask again.

Comment: If this is your problem, you should start to learn how to use Java by some books or online-tutorials. This is part of the basics, and no specific question.

Comment: Here is a pointer 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of the word in the text:

```
text.indexOf(word);
```

You can add this value to the array

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] findWord(String text, String word) throws NullPointerException
{
    int[] first = new int[text.length()];
    int j=0;
    for (int i = -1; (i = text.indexOf(word, i + 1)) != -1;) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    return first;
}
```

Here is my try, How can I add (i) to my array? It's just printing exactly needed numbers.

Answer (score 0):

create `ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`, then add elements to it by method `arrayList.add(int element)`, and then cast AL to array: `int[] result = arrayList.toArray(new int[arrayList.size()]);`

add() - adds elements to the end of ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

public int[] findWord(String text, String word) throws NullPointerException 
{

```
    int[] first = new int[text.length()];
    int j=0;
    for (int i = -1; (i = text.indexOf(word, i + 1)) != -1;j++) {
        first[j]=i;
    }
    int[] second = new int[j];
    second = Arrays.copyOf(first,j);
    return second;
```

}